# What's the meaning of " be high in indoctrination"?

Tags: meaning

In Evelyn Waugh's Loved Ones, there is a sentence: Mrs Komstock had...a nephew who was high in indoctrination:

> Wars simply don’t interest me. Everyone’s like that now. Well, I was
>   like that in ’43. So I went to the Beverly-Waldorf and worked in the
>   beauty parlor, but you couldn’t really get away from the war even
>   there. The ladies didn’t seem to have a mind for anything higher than
>   pattern-bombing. There was one lady who was worse than any of them,
>   called Mrs. Komstock. She came every Saturday morning for a blue rinse
>   and set and I seemed to take her fancy; she always asked for me; no
>   one else would do, but she never tipped me more than a quarter. Mrs.
>   Komstock had one son in Washington and one in Delhi, a grand-daughter
>   in Italy and **a nephew who was high in indoctrination** and I had to hear
>   everything about them all until it got so I dreaded Saturday mornings
>   more than any day in the week.

What's the meaning of "be high in indoctrination"?

Comment: Could you supply more of the context? I can think of a couple possible meanings.

Answer (score 2):

*Indoctrination* is US military jargon for various kinds of introductory training.

The events in this passage occur during WW II; searches in Google Books for *indoctrination* in works of that period usually concern the US Navy's Officer Indoctrination School, but there are also references to *indoctrination* for airmen.

Since Mrs. Komstock was old enough to have a (presumably adult) granddaughter in Italy, it is unlikely that her nephew was undergoing his own “basic training”; more likely he was a highly-ranked instructor, or was perhaps even more highly placed, as designer of some aspect of indoctrination curricula for the War Department.